# Typescript: declare module, export from another module

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have `a.d.ts`:

```
declare module './a' {
  export function foo(): string
}
```

And I want to re-export this foo from another module `b.d.ts`:

I tried:

1st try:

```
declare module './b' {
  export { foo } from './a'
}
```

2nd try:

```
declare module './b' {
  import { foo } from './a'

  export { foo }
}
```

but both times, when I do

```
// inside ./c.ts

import { foo } from './b';
// foo is not typed
```

Comment: try export {foo} from 'a' in 1st case or import {foo} from 'a' and export foo in the 2nd case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare module './b' {
  export { foo } from './a'
}
```

or

```
declare module './b' {
   import { foo } from './a'

   export foo
}
```

Comment: The code will not compile in the error `TS1194: Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace.`

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about ambient declaration, but here is how you do it with a concrete implementation:

a.ts

```
export function foo(): string {
  return 'a'
}
```

b.ts

```
export * from './a'
```

c.ts

```
import {foo} from './b'

foo() // returns string
```

Comment: Thanks. I need ambient declaration (didn't know they were called like that), because I'm adding typings to a .js file.

Comment: Try transpiling the concrete implementation and look at the generated declaration files.